# PHP 7.4.3 Arrays not inserting?

Tags: php

The entirety of this code works on other machines with PHP v 7.3 but my production machine is 7.4. Every time i go to print out the order creation data it just comes up blank. Trying to insert anything into the array using short syntax is just not working at all any ideas why. This little chunk is the offender in question and when printing out order creation data I don't get anything.

```
  $order_creation_data = array(
      'order' => array(
        'email' => $email,
        'fulfillment_status' => $shopify_fufillment_status,
        'financial_status' => 'paid',
      )
    );
      $shopify_address_build_array = array(
        'first_name' => $shopify_customer_default_address['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $shopify_customer_default_address['last_name'],
        'address1' => $shopify_customer_default_address['address1'],
        'address2' => $shopify_customer_default_address['address2'],
        'phone' => $shopify_customer_default_address['phone'],
        'city' => $shopify_customer_default_address['city'],
        'province' => $shopify_customer_default_address['province'],
        'country_code' => $shopify_customer_default_address['country_code'],
        'zip' => $shopify_customer_default_address['zip'],
      );

      $order_creation_data['order']['billing_address'] = $shopify_address_build_array;
      $order_creation_data['order']['shipping_address'] = $shopify_address_build_array;
```

Comment: There is no array short syntax.

Comment: Hi nicholas do you see any error.logs ? / maybe $shopify_customer_default_address is null or similar

Comment: No i've even set them to fixed strings just to test and nothing.

Comment: Have you tried dumping any values? Also, when you say it comes up blank, is it only the section you add later (the addresses) or the entire array? Or perhaps the whole page goes blank, indicating an error? How are you printing it, can you share the printing code?

Comment: @MarkusZeller `[]`?

Comment: @El_Vanja There is no array short syntax in OP question. Everything is written out as `array()`. Was not to be meant double meaning, LOL.